# How to refresh the switchery checkbox that is already being initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switchery

I've initialized the switchery using the below code.

```
var ss_is_schedule_edit = document.querySelector('.ss_is_schedule_edit');
var mySwitch = new Switchery(ss_is_schedule_edit, { color: '#8360c3' });
```

And I couldn't able to check/uncheck the switchery using the below code. it didn't worked.

```
$('.switchery').trigger('click');
```

Also, I've tried the below code but couldn't help.

```
mySwitch.setPosition(true);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with switchery.

Here is the solutions:

You can simply remove the existing switchery section using the below code.

```
$('.switchery').remove();
```

Then, you can initialize the switchery again using the below code.

```
var ss_is_schedule_edit = document.querySelector('.ss_is_schedule_edit');
var mySwitch = new Switchery(ss_is_schedule_edit, { color: '#8360c3' });
```

Thanks.